# Partitions of $\mathbb N$ which generate only divergent series of reciprocals of elements of those sets

Tags: divergent-series

This question is a result of some thinking about $\mathbb N$, divergent series and partitions of sets.

Although elementary, I am not skilled enough to answer it at the present moment.

> Is it possible to partition $\mathbb N$ into an infinite number of infinite sets $N_k=\{n_{mk}: m \in \mathbb N\};k\in \mathbb N$ in such a way that all the sums $\{S_w=\sum_{v=1}^{+ \infty}\dfrac{1}{n_{vw}}:w \in \mathbb N\}$ are divergent?

Of course, repetitions of elements in sets are not allowed.

I think that an answer to this question is "No.", because I think that if $S_w=+ \infty$ for all $w \in \mathbb N$ then at least two of the sets won´t be disjoint.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com; mathoverflow is a site for research-level mathematics.

Comment: @user44191 This is a research of the possibilities in theory of partitions of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: For you, it's research; for us, it's an undergraduate exercise.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I do not doubt that what you wrote is true.

Answer (score 3):

If we look for the most "natural" example I propose:

Let $N_k$ consist of all numbers with [2-adic absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#p-adic_absolute_value) equal to $2^{-k}$.

Comment: Another natural example (before the question is closed): $\mathbb{N}_k=$ set of numbers with exactly $k$ prime divisors.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch That one seems even more "natural".